# java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, uuid

I'm working on an Android app using Bluetooth connectivity between two paired smartphones. The Bluetooth logic is based on the famous BluetoothChat SDK example: a "service" Class managing a thread for server `accept()`, a thread for client `connect()` and a thread for reading/writing on the socket.

Everything works fine, except if I close an active connection (both from client or server side), then all successive attempts to start a new connection will fail with this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
```

After some research, I've come to think this is a problem with UUID. I'm using the UUID of the BTChat example (`fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66`), but the problem remains with another random UUID (it was `31ef5990-dc20-11e2-a28f-0800200c9a66`).

Here is the relevant client logcat. (The client `connect()` is what fails):

```
E/BluetoothService.cpp: stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
D/BluetoothService: Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: 30:17:C8:A7:C6:C3 fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66
        java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
```

The D-Bus error probably is caused by the `cancelDiscovery()` that Android docs suggests to call before `connect()`.  I think that `failed UUID channel lookup` is the real problem, but I have no idea how to fix this. Should I use another (well-known?) UUID?

If needed, I can show code snippets. Yet this problem is very logically similar to BluetoothChat.

Answer (score 4):

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

&

```
m = mAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] { int.class });
tmp = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(mAdapter, BLUETOOTH_CHANNEL);
```

Well .... I'm not a BT specialist, but I know that my code works without UUID using reflection. I don't think it's a good solution if you want something clean, but I just know that, in my case, it works (On 2.3.6) :)

Comment: Unfortunately the spp uuid doesn't solve it. The first connection is always working, the following ones not.

Comment: Well, I also had Service discovery failed on my first BT app. Then I used reflection to create socket : 

`m = mAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] { int.class });
tmp = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(mAdapter, BLUETOOTH_CHANNEL);` (With BLUETOOTH_CHANNEL the channel of the socket)
But when I changed original bluetoothChat code to that, I was able to connect/deconnect as much as i wanted :)

Comment: So, using reflection there is no more need of UUID? Instead I have to choose a BT channel?

Comment: Ok, with reflection seems working very fine! So, this is indeed an Android UUID bug or what?

Comment: I don't really know.
Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198487/are-connected-bluetoothsocket-rfcomm-channels-unique-regardless-of-uuid) can provide you an answer ?